# How can I eliminate a "not defined" warning referring to a java.util class in my BOM file?

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

I'm using ODM 8.5 (the JRules successor).  I generated a BOM from an existing Java project.  One of the generated classes in my bom file looks something like:

```
public class MyClass extends java.io.Serializable
{
    public java.util.UUID myId;
}
```

I get a warning:

```
[BOM] GBRMO0012W: Referenced type java.util.UUID is not defined
```

What do I need to do to get ODM to recognize Java classes in the BOM?  I also see similar warnings about java.sql.Timestamp and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try generating a new BOM entry based on your JRE XOM and containing the classes responsible for the warnings:

1. Launch the 'New BOM Entry' wizard (File -> New -> BOM Entry in the Rules perspective).
2. In the first page of the 'New BOM Entry' wizard click 'Next >' (the option 'Create a BOM entry from a XOM' should be selected by default).
3. In the second page of the 'New BOM Entry' wizard, click on the 'Browse XOM...' button. The 'Browse XOM' dialog should pop-up.
4. In the 'Browse XOM' dialog, select the entry corresponding to your JRE, then click 'OK'.

[image: 'Browse XOM' Dialog]

5. In the 'New BOM Entry' wizard, tick the classes you are interested in, then click 'Finish'.

[image: BOM class selection in the 'New BOM Entry' wizard]

Note that it worked fine for me for java.util.UUID but I suspect that depending of which classes and members are imported into your BOM entry, you could end-up with other (lots of?) similar warnings.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any other way to get rid of those...